# how to remove prefix of attribute in tag of XML?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I need to remove inside the xml one tag's attribute. and for this I find a solution to use xslt:

```
      <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

it works well, even too much because after the removing procedure, the necessary attributes become without prefix but also without content. For some reason, both  the prefix and the content are truncated, only an empty attribute remains, for example, the attr "xsi:type" which prefix should be removed:

```
<out:Declarant xsi:type="out:RequestAccount">
```

was expected this:

```
<out:Declarant type="out:RequestAccount">
```

but got this:

```
<out:Declarant type="">
```

I do not understand why the content of "type" is deleted?

here is where my xsd file to xmls :
[xsd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsVBa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `type` is deleted because `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />` selects child nodes (and attributes) of the current attribute, but attributes do not have child nodes (or attributes) like elements do.

Instead, just do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

Comment: thx for message. But it still empty attr after transforming.. sorry

Comment: Are you sure you changed the right template? See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJW for an example of it working